# Python Group Values in a Nested List At Corresponding Indexes

Tags: python, list, numpy

Given a list nested with numpy lists, I want to go through each index in each corresponding list and keep track of the count depending on the element, which would be stored into a single list.

The minimum runnable code example below better showcases the problem.

```
import numpy as np


lst = [
    np.array([1,0,1]),
    np.array([1,1,1]),
    np.array([2,2,1])
]
print(lst)

#Problem, take count of each corresponding index within list
#If the element == 2, subtract one. If it's 1, add 1. 0 has no value
#Make the output just one list with the calculated count for each index

#Expected output:
#lst = [1, 0, 3]
# 1 in index 0 because there's two 1s in each lists first index, but a 2 subtracts one from the count
# 0 in index 1 since there's one 1 which brings the count to 1, but a 2 subtracts one from the count
# 3 in index 2 since there's three 1's, adding 3 to the count.
```

I have looked into `from collections import defaultdict` and `from itertools import groupby`, but I couldn't understand how to use that to do anything else but sort a nested list.

Apologies if this issue is within the two sources I provided above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the inner arrays have the same length you could transform it into a 2-dimensional array to leverage numpy vectorization:

```
# transform into two dimensional array
arr = np.array(lst)

# set -1 where values are equals to 2
t = np.where(arr == 2, -1, arr)

# sum across first axis (each corresponding positions on the inners lists)
res = t.sum(axis=0).tolist()

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 0, 3]
```

Comment: How would you assign multiple elements to different values? For example, how would you do both t = np.where(arr == 2, -1, arr) and n = np.where(arr == 1, 5, arr), but still be able to call sum(axis=0).tolist()?

Comment: @MachineMachzor you could call np.where two times in the same array? Not sure if I understood your question